# Find parent directory of a path

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, path, nsfilemanager

Is there any way to find the parent directory of a path using `NSFileManager` or something?

e.g. Take this:

> /path/to/something

And turn it into

> /path/to/

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The `NSString` method `-stringByDeletingLastPathComponent` does just that.

You can use it like this:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [@"/tmp/afolder" stringByDeletingLastPathComponent]);
```

And it will log `/tmp`.

Answer (score 18):

Usually file URLs are of type `NSURL`. There's now a method you can use to grab the parent directory:
    `NSURL *parentDirectory = [fileURL URLByDeletingLastPathComponent];`

Comment: If the URL is for the root of the file system, i.e. `file:///`, then the result of `deletingLastPathComponent()` will be `file:///../`. So, in most cases, you should handle that as a special case.

Answer (score 14):

You should use URL for file locations. If you have a path as String I would convert it to URL. For **Swift 3** use

```
let fileURL: URL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/path/to/something")
let folderURL = fileURL.deletingLastPathComponent()
```